# change select option from another select option selected?

Tags: jquery

I have two select box in a modal Boostrap:

```
<select name="event_status" id="event_status" class="form-control mb-1" required>
    <option value="in progress">in progress</option>
    <option value="ended">ended</option>
</select>

<select name="event_picto" id="event_picto" class="form-control mb-1" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>traffic status...</option>
    <option value="img/eventgreen.svg">normal</option>
    <option value="img/eventyellow.svg">under conditions</option>
    <option value="img/eventred.svg">closed</option>
</select>
```

i would like that if option value "ended" is selected so option value of second select box is set to "normal".

i try this but no change :

```
$("#event_status").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "ended") {
        $("event_picto").html("<option value='img/eventgreen.svg'>normal</option>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo.  The selector is missing the `#` character.

Comment: You set the value in a similar way to get the value: `$("event_picto").val("img/eventgreen.svg")` - if you use `.html` you replace the entire content - ie remove all the other `<option>`s  (typo aside ofc)

Comment: i miss # character, but if use this there are no change : `$("#event_picto")val("img/eventgreen.svg");`

Comment: @StevenSavior: Another typo, the call to `.change()` is never closed.  This is a syntax error and would be reported on your browser's development console.  Always check there first.

Comment: It seems to work fine in a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0y86Lmh7

Comment: Solved with this. Thanks to all :  
  `if (val == "Terminé") {
      $('#event_picto > option[value="img/eventgreen.svg"]').attr("selected", true);  
  }`